# Google Sheet Query Based on Matching Columns to Other Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Given this Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E6OjzpFvTyq3I9WCMhu4Mhx54kLxyvZkBAA4_nVba_w/edit?usp=sharing):

I have the following tabs:

```
Leads To Date
All Enrolled To Date
Leads Never Enrolled
```

I need the last tab `Leads Never Enrolled` to have every record from `Leads To Date` that is not in `All Enrolled To Date`, per the columns `First Name` and `Last Name`.

I have tried using the QUERY function, but I'm not sure how to integrate matching on first and last names within the search argument.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER('Leads To Date'!A:C,COUNTIF('All Enrolled To Date'!A:A&'All Enrolled To Date'!B:B,'Leads To Date'!A:A&'Leads To Date'!B:B)=0)
```

[image]

Comment: **Be careful**. Your provided answer will produce false results if there are common names in  both your `Leads To Date` tab and `All Enrolled To Date` as well. Those common names will come up as `Leads Never Enrolled`.

Comment: @marikamitsos Yes, you are right. Thanks. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following formula

```
=FILTER(A3:C, ISNA(MATCH(A3:A&B3:B, E3:E&F3:F, 0)))
```

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

By using ampersands `&` we join 2 columns creating 1 virtual column resulting the first and last names as one unique value like `CaseJustin`.
We then use these virtual columns to filter the rest of our ranges.

[image]

Functions used:

- [`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)
- [`ISNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093293)
- [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)

Comment: **Be careful**. The accepted answer will produce false results if there are common names in  both your `Leads To Date` tab and `All Enrolled To Date` as well. Those common names will come up as `Leads Never Enrolled`.