# Google Sheet Filter between two tabs

Tags: google-sheets

[Given this Google Sheet:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kwOf_B0LU--ojuTvi4dFCUb4sl-BHexi/view?usp=sharing)

I have the following tabs: (“Leads To Date”), (“All Enrolled To Date”) and (“Leads Never Enrolled”)

I need the last tab ("Leads Never Enrolled") to have every record from ("Leads To Date") that are not in ("All Enrolled To Date"), per the columns "First Name" and "Last Name".

The formula currently being used is:
=FILTER('Leads To Date'!A:B,'Leads To Date'!A:A<>'All Enrolled To Date'!A:A,'Leads To Date'!B:B<>'All Enrolled To Date'!B:B)

I essentially need it to search the ("Leads To Date") tab for any matches in the ("All Enrolled To Date") tab and then send the unmatched results to the ("Leads Never Enrolled") tab.

**The following are currently in the (“Leads To Date”) tab:**

Johnny Appleseed

George Washington

Jane Dough

John Doe

**The (“All Enrolled To Date”) tab includes:**

Jane Dough

John Doe

**So the (“Leads Never Enrolled”) should be:**

Johnny Appleseed

George Washington

However, the result in the (“Leads Never Enrolled”) tab still includea all 4 names as if nothing was filtered.

Comment: I believe that [this is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64761661/1527780) that you are looking for.

Comment: Your Sheet is not shared publicly